# why can't I change the width and height properties of a raised button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on this simple app and I can't seem to change the width and height properties of a raised button, I also tried using a flat button but it doesn't work either.[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9ZYh.png)

```
Row (mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
           children: <Widget>[
             RaisedButton(
               height: 20,
               color: Colors.green,
               onPressed: () {
                 setState(() { });
               },
```

Error message: The named parameter 'height' isn't defined.  Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'height'.

Comment: Please include formatted code in the body of your question. You can format code blocks using three backticks (`) or tildes (~) on the lines before and after your code. More formatting help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Error messages should also be included in the body of your post.

Comment: I have formatted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the link [raisedButton doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html)

You need to wrap the button widget with button theme widget after that you are ready to go. I put a example code:

```
ButtonTheme(
  minWidth: 200.0,
  height: 100.0,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("test"),
  ),
);
```

Comment: but why though according to the flutter documentation it should have properties like height and minWidth.

Comment: if you check Constructors there is not a properties like height and minWidth. They are under the Properties headline and the button has the properties but to set that you need to use another widget.

Comment: but it is listed under properties, I'm getting really confused

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your Raised Button with other widget that pass his contraints, like Container

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 50,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: this.action,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Text('Title', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Isn't the button supposed to have a height property by itself?

Comment: RaisedButton does not have a property to set its size by itself. It can inherit constraints from a parent